# German dependent visa to regular working visa

Tags: working-visas, germany

I came to Germany on a dependent visa and started doing a Master's course. Now that my course is about to end and I am in the process of finding a job, I would like to know if I can convert the dependent visa status to a regular working visa by showing my employment contract.

If anyone on this forum has done this, could you please let me know the process to be followed.

Comment: When you say "dependant visa", do you mean your spouse has a work visa and you are in Germany with them?

Comment: Yes @nkjt. My spouse has a work visa and has recently received the Blue card. I am still on a dependent visa.

Comment: http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html - you have the right to a residence permit allowing work without restrictions if he/she has a Blue Card, but I'm not sure of the process (if they recently received the Blue Card you probably need to update your status).

Comment: I would not like to remain on the dependent visa but would like to convert this visa to an independent work visa. I would like to know if this is possible and if yes, the procedure. @nkjt

Answer (score 1):

While you may be able to get your own [Blue Card](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) through employment, you may be unable to change your status within Germany. It can depend on conditions attached to your visa.

According to the Federal Office for Migration and Refugees (BAMF) report on 
[Opportunities to change the residence title and the purpose of stay in Germany](https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/Publikationen/EMN/Studien/wp67-emn-wechsel-aufenthaltstiteln-aufenthaltszwecken.pdf?__blob=publicationFile)

> Third-country nationals usually need a residence title if they want to stay in Germany for a longer period of time. The issuance of a specific residence title and the rights and conditions attached to it depend on the purpose of the migrant’s stay. If the purpose of stay changes, the authorities will need to examine whether the residence title is still valid or can be extended, whether another type of residence title might be more appropriate or whether the rights and conditions linked to the residence title need to be changed due to the new purpose of stay. Changes of residence status may also be possible if the person in question has held a residence title for several years and meets certain other criteria to receive another one.

However, this is not to say that you are unable to remain in Germany on your own, with an independent right of residence, and you would need to discuss your options through the authorities at the [BAMF](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Willkommen/Aufenthalt/aufenthalt-node.html).